# Opening files(docx,pptx,pdf ) in phonegap with iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to create an app which downloads various files from internet(docx,pptx and so on).

The  download part is working fine. Files are getting downloaded in Documents folder for app.

Now I need open these files in their default application(`DOcumentTogo, Office SUits` and so.).

Can anybody suggest a `phonegap/cordova` plugin of `iOS` or even code snippet to open files will also do.

I'll manage to add it to plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Use object element in html 5, it may help you
eg:

```
>  <object width="400" height="400" data="p.pdf"></object>
```

it will show
 pdf file inside our app(tested in ios)

Comment: but what about docx,pttx files?